# JS file not running with Node.js in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use node.js in my Command Prompt to run a js file but the terminal is saying this and not running the file.

```
>hello.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
console.log(hello world)
                                                                      ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

New error log:

```
hello.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
console.log(hello world)
                                                                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

solved: cd into the folder that the file is in then open the js file with node

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file you are trying to run?

Comment: `console.log(hello world)` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: This is the contents of the file i was trying to run: console.log('hello world');

Comment: You claim that the code you write is different from the code printed in the error. This is not the case for my node version. A string literal is printed as a string literal, including quotation marks. Which node version are you using? It looks like there may be a bunch of unprintable characters after the function call. Delete those. Make sure you are actually editing the right file and are not executing the wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

Notice in the error log that hello world is not a string, looks like two different variables. Think what was intended was `'hello world'`. Node is complaining about an argument list because the code is being interpreted as a list of arguments like `console.log(someVariableFoo, someVariableBar)` since there is a space between `hello` and `world` and the text is not wrapped in quotes.

A string in JavaScript looks like:

```
const a = 'Hello World'; // single quote
const b = "Hello World"; // double quote 
const c = `Hello World`; // template literal
```

> hello.js:1
>   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
>   console.log(**hello world**)

More on strings via MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Hello, i tried to fix it, but it still gives me the error log. This is the new code: console.log('Hello world!');

Comment: Hello Emir, what is the new error log output. Could you please edit your question above and include this below your original question? Or open a new question? Would also be helpful as Daniel commented above to post the entirety of the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
console.log("hello world");
}
```

make hello world string inside the quotes and make sure to close the curly braces